# Unable to access folder structure after installing updates on Debian Squeeze

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian

So I had a perfectly good running Debian system whereby I could access my apache root by going to 73.xx.xx.xx and see my home page. Also could access sub folders by going to 73.xx.xx.xx/site1     73.xx.xx.xx.xx/site2

I did a apt software upgrade and now I can still go to 73.xx.xx.xx and see the home page however I am unable to see the sub folders. Did the upgrade override a setting and if so which one?

I tried looking in httpd.conf but nothing in there. Any pointers?

UPDATE:

```
Tue May 01 16:30:35 2012] [notice] child pid 7557 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue May 01 16:33:49 2012] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue May 01 16:33:49 2012] [notice] seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
[Thu May 03 02:14:01 2012] [warn] pid file /var/run/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu May 03 02:14:01 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze8 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 03 02:14:47 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu May 03 02:14:48 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze8 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 03 02:15:25 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu May 03 02:15:26 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze8 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 03 02:19:07 2012] [error] [client 99.172.40.89] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 03 02:19:09 2012] [error] [client 99.172.40.89] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 03 02:19:11 2012] [error] [client 99.172.40.89] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 03 02:22:43 2012] [error] [client 99.172.40.89] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 03 02:23:57 2012] [error] [client 99.172.40.89] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 03 02:24:01 2012] [error] [client 99.172.40.89] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 03 02:26:26 2012] [error] [client 99.172.40.89] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Comment: What do you see instead of the contents of the directory?

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 73.xx.xx.xx

Comment: Check `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and see if there's anything useful there

Comment: If it could not connect, then the server is down, and the root of the site shouldn't work either.  Make sure you're not seeing cached pages.

Comment: @ShaneMadden http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1695 It's probably Chrome's "Friendly" Error Page

Comment: The only thing I see in logs are a bunch of segmentation faults. This is weird because I have had a very clean system. All I did was a apt-get upgrade and this happened.  I have never had problems. I mean I have jenkins running on port 8080 as that did not got affected. also at 80 is working as I am able to pull up a dummy page.

Comment: I thought earlier that it was just PHP files that I could not pull up..but I created a test folder and put an index.html in it and same thing. Firefox and Chrome both cannot connect.

Comment: @DerfK Huh?  Chrome's friendly errors tell you what's going on - the 404 screenshotted in that bug report says "404 - File Not Found"; what they're complaining about is that it doesn't show the returned body if it's under a certain size, similar to IE's behavior.

Comment: @ShaneMadden and yet if it's able to cause segfaults, it had to have been able to connect.  The browser's error pages aren't always helpful ;)

Comment: @DerfK Hah, fair enough! jini, is there any other helpful text on the error pages the browsers are giving you?  Given those segfaults, I'm guessing they're getting connection resets.

Comment: ok so this is weird. I restarted apache2 a few times while monitoring my /var/log/apache2/error.log. Now everything works?? Please see the contents of my apache error log (50 lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check through your browser modules and see if there are any modules you've installed manually that didn't get upgraded with the rest of Debian.  I believe I once saw something like this happen with a custom version of mod_security that only crashed the server once there was a subdirectory in the request.  If you built modules yourself, see [this link](http://blog.arithm.com/2008/02/09/how-to-segfault-apache-2-with-mod_security/) and make sure you have the right `apache2-foo-dev` package installed.